# How can I sort a list of strings in Dart?

Tags: string, list, sorting, dart

I see in the API docs there is a `sort()` method on `List`,  but I'm not clear what it needs for a parameter. The current need is for a very simple straight up alpha comparison.

Answer (score 150):

## 1. A Quick Solution

Thanks for the question! You can sort a list of `String`s like this:

```dart
main() {
  final List<String> fruits = <String>['bananas', 'apples', 'oranges'];
  fruits.sort();
  print(fruits);
}
```

The above code prints:

```
[apples, bananas, oranges]
```

## 2. Slightly more advanced usage

Notice that `sort()` does not return a value. It sorts the list without creating a new list. If you want to sort and print in the same line, you can use *method cascades*:

```dart
print(fruits..sort());
```

For more control, you can define your own comparison logic. Here is an example of sorting the fruits based on price.

```dart
main() {
  final List<String> fruits = <String>['bananas', 'apples', 'oranges'];
  fruits.sort((a, b) => getPrice(a).compareTo(getPrice(b)));
  print(fruits);
}
```

Let's see what's going on here.

A `List` has a [sort](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/be/dartdoc-viewer/dart:core.List#id_sort) method, which has one *optional* parameter: a [Comparator](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/continuous/dart_core/Comparator.html). A Comparator is a `typedef` or function alias. In this case, it's an alias for a function that looks like:

```dart
int Comparator(T a, T b)
```

From the docs:

> A Comparator function represents such a total ordering by returning a negative integer if a is smaller than b, zero if a is equal to b, and a positive integer if a is greater than b.

## 3. How to do it with a list of custom objects

Additionally, if you create a list composed of custom objects, you could add the `Comparable<T>` as a `mixin` or as inheritance (`extends`) and then override the `compareTo` method, in order to recreate the standard behavior of `sort()` for your list of custom objects. For more info, do check out [this other, related StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55308336/4756173).

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry to complain but while I am trying to appreciate the apparent versatility of the above, I do not find it intuitive or inline with previous language experience.  Do you guys have somebody with a square wooden mouse and a long grey beard coming up with some of this stuff?  :)

Comment: This is a weird historical artifact. The comparator should be optional. It used to be, but we changed the optional parameter syntax a while back, which forced us to make all parameters non-optional for a while, including this one. We just haven't gotten a chance to fix this and make it optional again yet.

Comment: Thanks @munificent glad to hear it'll get fixed soon. See bug http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=1235

Comment: I've updated the answer based on the new API. Much simpler now :)

Answer (score 28):

Here is the one line code to achieve it.

```
fruits.sort((String a, String b)=>a.compareTo(b)); //fruits is of type List<String>
```

Answer (score 13):

##### For Sorting Simple List of Integers or Strings:

```
var list = [5 , -5 ,1];
list.sort(); //-5 , 1 , 5
```

##### For Reversing the list order:

```
list.reversed;
```

##### For Sorting List of Objects or Map by field of it:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> list= [
    {"name": "Shoes", "price": 100},
    {"name": "Pants", "price": 50},
  ];

// from low to high according to price
list.sort((a, b) => a["price"].compareTo(b["price"]));
  
// from high to low according to price
list.sort((a, b) => b["price"].compareTo(a["price"]));
```

Answer (score 10):

To add just one point to Seth's detailed answer, in general, in

```
(a, b) => foo(a, b)
```

passed into `sort`, the function `foo` should answer an integer result as follows:

- if a < b, result should be < 0,
- if a = b, result should be = 0, and
- if a > b, result should be > 0.

For the above law of trichotomy to hold, both `a` and `b` must be `Comparable`s.

Answer (score 9):

use [`compareAsciiUpperCase`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/compareAsciiUpperCase.html) instead of `compareTo`, as it supports strings and automatically ignores case sensitive:

```dart
import "package:collection/collection.dart";

data.sort((a, b) {
  return compareAsciiUpperCase(a.name, b.name);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

After today, you should just be able to do  list.sort() .
The sort method's argument is now optional, and it defaults to a function that calls compareTo  on the elements themselves. Since String is Comparable, it should Just Work now.

Comment: Was the List sort() method ever fixed to not require a comparator function?  Or was there a regression? I'm using Dart 0.2.6.0_r15355 on Ubuntu 12.04 and getting the following results: [3,1,2].sort()==null and
['a','c','b'].sort()==null.

Comment: Oops! Dart was sorting the array:-)  But the sort() function returns void:-(  So "print([3,1,2].sort())'" outputs "null".  In this case, the Dart devs are not implementing a fluent programming style.  I wish they would. Because then you could use the result of calling sort() immediately.

Answer (score -2):

How I have solved this problem.

```
  List<Product> _dataSavingListProducts = [];
  List<Product> _dataSavingListFavoritesProducts = [];

  void _orderDataSavingLists() {
    _dataSavingListProducts.toList().reversed;
    _dataSavingListFavoritesProducts.toList().reversed;
  }
```

Comment: Reversing != sorting...