# Is there a way to sort a listview in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a simple notes app, in which I am using ListTiles to show all the notes saved. Is there a way I can sort this listview after it is built?

Comment: I am new to flutter. Please help

Comment: You are supposed to sort the list that the listview is holding. The listview has no idea what a list is

Comment: Ok. I figured a way to load the data in the list and sort that list. How do I close the question? Also us there a way to insert data in a sorted database in sqllite?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to sort list of songs from external storage alphabetically in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54065146/how-to-sort-list-of-songs-from-external-storage-alphabetically-in-flutter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can sort the `ListView` after creating it. The way to do it is to

1. First `sort` your data.
2. Then pass the sorted data to the `ListView` widget.

You can check out this [doc for dart's sort method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/List/sort.html).

For your task, you have to create your own comparator to sort your data. And at the end just pass the data to the `LlistView`!