# Flutter; Sort List of Widgets

Tags: list, flutter, sorting

I currently have a list of widgets

```
List<LessonItem> _lessons = [];
```

One Widget inside this list, added by the user should look like this

```
LessonItem('Bio', 'Mrs Pithan', 'A1.012', HourMinute('08', '00'),
        HourMinute('11', '50'), Colors.green), //lesson, teacher, room, from, to, color
```

Now I want to sort the list by a specific property from the widgets. How can I do that?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dart comparison operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55297580/dart-comparison-operators)

Comment: can you elaborate the property by which you want to sort...like time difference or so?..
by the way you can use sort() function with comapreTo function to get your target result. See here [Sort method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.0/dart-core/List/sort.html#:~:text=sort%20method%20Null%20safety&text=Sorts%20this%20list%20according%20to,must%20act%20as%20a%20Comparator.&text=The%20default%20List%20implementations%20use,compare%20if%20compare%20is%20omitted.)

Comment: The 'from' property in a 'ListItem' is kept inside another widget 'HourMinute' (two strings). I want to merge these two strings (in this example '08' and '00'), convert them to integers, then to minutes (first string * 60) and then compare them with the other widgets. Finally I want to reorder them from the lowest to the highest number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try with the sort method in dart.

You choose a property you want to sort by, and then define how any two elements will be compared.

Here I'm comparing each element by id (smaller id would en up first after sort):

```
  _lessons.sort((LessonItem a, LessonItem b) => a.id - b.id);
```

In this case I'm sorting by name (with the compareTo() method from String):

```
  _lessons.sort((LessonItem a, LessonItem b) => a.name.compareTo(b.name));
```

You can find more detailed info and some examples in:
[dart documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.0/dart-core/List/sort.html)
and
[this helpful post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dart-sort-a-list/)

Comment: Yes, thanks,it looks good. Where can I insert this sort method? If I do it directly under the list, I get an error with my stateful widget. Do I need a new function for this?

Comment: Well, it depends in the structure of your widget. You generally should be able to call sort() right after you fill your list with items. So some questions i should ask are: 1) How does your code look? and 2) What error message are you getting?

Comment: I had to wrap it inside an ```initState()```. Thanks for your help!