# How to create sort method in Dart?

Tags: sorting, dart

Given a `List<String>` of months, how do I create my own sort method in Dart?
Consider this [relevant link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888206/how-can-i-sort-a-list-of-strings-in-dart).

The **sorting order** would be:

```dart
["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
```

**Example**

Given:

```dart
List<String> months = ["October", "January", "July"];
```

The expected output is:

```dart
["January", "July", "October"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [`List.sort` method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/sort.html).
With the sorting order you provided, you can use `indexOf` to get an integer value that represent the sorting "weight" and then use [`num.compareTo`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/num/compareTo.html) to return a *negative* value if element `a` should appear before element `b`, i.e. the `indexOf` value is smaller, and a *positive* value if it should appear after element `b`:

```dart
const List<String> sortingOrder = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April',
  'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

List<String> months = ['October', 'January', 'July'];
months.sort((a, b) => sortingOrder.indexOf(a).compareTo(sortingOrder.indexOf(b)));

print(months); // [January, July, October]
```

This way, you can obviously very easily create any kind of sorting order that sorts different kinds of values.

Comment: .indexOf would be expensive to use repeatedly.  You should create a map that maps January to 1, February to 2, and so on, and sort by that.