# How to send the messges in order when using whatsapp package in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, whatsapi

I have a list of messages which need to be sent to different people. In the preview page, the list is in order. But when I press send it goes to WhatsApp chat one by one to send the message but randomly. How to make it in sequence as it is shown in the preview message? Can someone help me with this?
I'm calling preview page here:

```
 if (messages.isNotEmpty) {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => PreviewPage(messages)));
        }
```

This is the preview page

```
import 'package:android_intent/android_intent.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PreviewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map> msgList;
  final String baseURL = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=";
  PreviewPage(this.msgList);

  @override

    widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Preview Message"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          //msgList = SortedMap(Ordering.byValue());
          // print(msgList["phone"]);
          for (var msg in msgList) {
            print('printing message');
            print(msg["phone"]);
            if (msg["phone"] != null) {
              var url = "${baseURL}91${msg['phone']}&text=${msg['messages']}";
              print(url);
              AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
                  action: 'action_view',
                  data: Uri.encodeFull(url),
                  // flags: <int>[Flag.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP],
                  package: "com.whatsapp.w4b");
              await intent.launch();
            }
          }
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.send),
      ),
```

Comment: Mention the links to preview page and package used.

Comment: Can you help me send messages in the same order messages are saved

Comment: What is the order you need?  Is it alphabetical? [List sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12889025/13625305)

Comment: In this I create a group of contacts and when I press send it takes to the whatsapp chat one by one but it isn't in the order I saved the contacts.

Comment: I tried list sorting but it won't work in my case. the msg in mesgList is sorted in the way I want. But when it is calling WhatsApp it becomes random.

Comment: Can you add some sample data that can be used to recreate the sorting issue ?

Comment: Preview page has a list of messages 
list tile  1 : ABC, phone no of ABC
list tile  2 : XYZ, phone no of XYZ

When I press send it takes me to the whatsapp chat screen of XYZ first then ABC or vice versa randomnly. I want it to go to ABC first.

Comment: ok. Do those print statements show output in correct order ?

Comment: I think the problem is  due to `async` nature of the call to `intent.launch()`  you might have to use `await intent.launch();`

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the `OnPressed` to be `async` and use `await intent.launch();` with reference to [android-intent package](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent)

```
onPressed: () async {
            //msgList = SortedMap(Ordering.byValue());
            // print(msgList["phone"]);
            for (var msg in msgList) {
              print('printing message');
              print(msg["phone"]);
              if (msg["phone"] != null) {
                var url = "${baseURL}91${msg['phone']}&text=${msg['messages']}";
                print(url);
                AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
                    action: 'action_view',
                    data: Uri.encodeFull(url),
                    // flags: <int>[Flag.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP],
                    package: "com.whatsapp.w4b");
                await intent.launch();
              }
            }
          },
```

Code given below is for sorting. Created a class for organizing the message details like contact number, contact name, message content. This helps in applying `sort` function on the basis of contact name later on. If needed modify `sort` on basis of other properties.

Reference for [List.sort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53549197/13625305)

```
class MessageHolder {
  int contactNumber;
  String messageContent;
  String contactName;
  MessageHolder({this.contactName, this.contactNumber, this.messageContent});
  
  @override
  String toString(){
    return '$contactName, $contactNumber, $messageContent';
  }
}

void main() {
  List<MessageHolder> messages = [
    MessageHolder(
        contactName: 'DEF', contactNumber: 2345678901, messageContent: 'Two'),
    MessageHolder(
        contactName: 'ABC', contactNumber: 1234567890, messageContent: 'One'),
    
    MessageHolder(
        contactName: 'GHI', contactNumber: 3456789012, messageContent: 'Three'),
    MessageHolder(
        contactName: 'XYZ', contactNumber: 3456789012, messageContent: 'Four'),
  ];
  
  List<MessageHolder> sortedMessages = messages..sort((a, b) => a.contactName.compareTo(b.contactName));
  
  for(MessageHolder message in sortedMessages){
    print(message);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
ABC, 1234567890, One
DEF, 2345678901, Two
GHI, 3456789012, Three
XYZ, 3456789012, Four
```

Comment: I tried async but still doesn't work and yes preview shows the message in order.

Comment: Updated to include sorting

Comment: The problem isn't with the list sorting, the problem is when the list is sent to the whatsapp api.

Comment: ok understood but we are sending one element at a time from the list and `await`ing for it to complete. If the API is maintaining order in an internal list then there might be nothing we can do to reorder. Cannot find any other way as of now. Can you add a link to the API doc or reference ?