# How to get distance between users in listview flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore collection with one of the fields of documents containing locations(geopoints) of users, I want build a `listview` with distance between current user and all other users in ascending order. How do I achieve in flutter?

It looks something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXfME.png

***Update***

How can I get location from document in a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**STEP 1 :** Get the distance of current user with present list item in kilometers

```
var distanceInKms = GetDistance(latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2);


double GetDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) 
{
  
    var p = 0.017453292519943295;
    var c = cos;
    var a = 0.5 - c((lat2 - lat1) * p)/2 + 
          c(lat1 * p) * c(lat2 * p) * 
          (1 - c((lon2 - lon1) * p))/2;
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a));
  
}
```

**STEP 2 :** Add these values to the list item object. And Sort the list based on this field.

```
myList.sort((a,b) => a.distance.compareTo(b.distance));
```

Refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12889025/13892187) for further info on sorting.

**Question:** Hi, thanks how do i return this in listview and how do I get document from firestore in a list?

**Answer** :

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection("YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME").getDocuments();

List<items> myList = [];

snapshot.documents.forEach((doc) {
      //Convert incoming JSON info to object of your type and add to list
      myList.add(List.fromJSON(doc.data));
    });

//Apply logic on myList for sorting based on location
```

Comment: Hi, thanks how do i return this in ```listview``` and how do I get document from firestore in a list?