# FlutterFlow: Sort collection of DocumentReference

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm using the NoCode-app Flutterflow - and I need a piece of code ;) to sort a firestore-collection. I'm sure it can't be that hard, but I'm trying this for 2 days now...

I want the function to return a sorted list, based on a string-argument.

When I create a "custom function" (that's how a piece of code is called in FlutterFlow) I get this template:

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

List<DocumentReference> sortImages(
  List<DocumentReference> listdocument,
  String sortBy,
) {
  return listdocument; '<<< what comes here? How do I sort?
}
```

How do I sort "sortImages" now by the argument "sortBy" and return it?

As you see I don't really have an idea of flutter/darts, and a NoSQL-db is also new to me... but I keep fighting to learn more every day!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I would also need to group by in Flutterflow

Comment: No, sorry, I didn't tackle that yet. But I think now you can do it within FlutterFlow, without a custom function

Answer (score 0):

sorry if it's too late, but have you read this post?
[How can I sort a list of strings in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888206/how-can-i-sort-a-list-of-strings-in-dart)

There is a explanation of how to order string with different alternatives. This example should work in your custom function:

```
final List<String> fruits = <String>['bananas', 'apples', 'oranges'];
fruits.sort();
print(fruits);
```

Cheers!

Ariel-.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).