# Firestore: Order documents in where query

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fetch the most liked posts of the last few days (3 days in this example).

```
Timestamp maxDaysAgoTimestamp =
        Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 3)));
Query query = FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("posts")
            .where("timestamp",
                isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: maxDaysAgoTimestamp)
            .orderBy("likes", descending: true)
            .limit(10);
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await query.get();
```

I am trying to achieve this with the above query, but I am getting the following error.

```
Failed assertion: line 492 pos 13: 'conditionField == orders[0][0]':
The initial orderBy() field "[[FieldPath([likes]), true]][0][0]" has to be
the same as the where() field parameter "FieldPath([timestamp])" when an inequality
operator is invoked.
```

Appearently I would have to add an ordering on the `timestamp` as the first ordering, but then it would order by `timestamp` first and only consider the `likes` ordering when the timestamp is the same which is useless.

So am I doing something wrong? Or do you have any other ideas I could implement this use case?

In my opinion this use case is not too special, so there should be a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear:

The problem is that you can't have it sorted by a field that's different than the field used in an inequality operator (`isGreaterThanOrEqualTo` in this case).

This basically means that since you're filtering using `.where()` on `/timestamp`, you need to `orderBy` in the same field as `/timestamp`.

The solution would therefore be to filter *locally*, after fetching the query. Something like:

```
docs.sort((a, b) => a.data()['likes'].compareTo(b.data()['likes']));
```

###### See also

[How can I sort a list of strings in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888206/how-can-i-sort-a-list-of-strings-in-dart)

Comment: thank you, while this works it does not exactly achieve what I want, as you typically always fetch a batch with limit() and like this you only sort the post by likes of the batch, but you dont get the most liked posts of the last few days